# flutter Column Childs perfectly centred

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'am trying to achieve a similar result as the following image
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6lUz.png)
using the following code :

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 0),
            height: 60,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomPaint(painter: CircleHelper()),
                Container(height: 7),
                Container(
                    height: 40,
                    child: VerticalDivider(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent))
              ],
            ))
```

as result I got :
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R0k5.png)

as u can see they are not perfectly centre;

Thx for your help

Comment: Try to activate debug painting and see what is going on. My guess: The `CustomPaint` Widget takes the full width and does not center the drawn circle.

Comment: hey @puelo , your suggestion helped me a lot thx , the issue was on the CustomPaint indeed. thx

Answer (score 0):

Use a Stack widget to place a circle container over a divider. Here's the code.

note: VerticalDivider didn't work as expected. I used  Divider widget and I wrapped it with a Transform.rotate widget and rotate it 90 degrees (pi / 2). You'll need to import 'dart:math'.

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            Transform.rotate(
                angle: pi / 2,
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                )),
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 20,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 20,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```